# Go Template get a variable dynamically

Tags: go, templates, variables, dynamic, gomplate

I have yml parameters that look like

```
nodes: one, two
instanceMinOne: 1
instanceMaxOne: 2
instanceMinTwo: 4
instanceMaxTwo: 6
```

Is there a way with go templating to dynamically read for example instanceMin**One** where the variable name is composed of `instanceMin` + the dynamic value coming from the nodes list ?

something like (this obviously doesn't work but just give the idea of what I'd like to achieve)

```
{{ - range $nodeName := (split .Parameters.nodes) } } } }
   instance-min: {{ .Parameters.instanceMin$nodeName }}
   instance-max: {{ .Parameters.instanceMan$nodeName }}
{{ - end }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to solve 2 tasks:

- string concatenation
- indexing with a dynamic value

For concatenation you may use the builtin `print` function, e.g.

```
{{ $key := print "instanceMin" $nodeName }}
```

For indexing, use the builtin `index` function:

```
instance-min: {{ index $.Parameters $key }}
```

(Note: The `{{range}}` action changes the dot, so inside it you need `$` to reference outside of the loop variable.)

Or in one line:

```
instance-min: {{ index $.Parameters (print "instanceMin" $nodeName) }}
```

See a runnable demo:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

    params := map[string]any{
        "Parameters": map[string]any{
            "nodes":          []string{"One", "Two"},
            "instanceMinOne": 1,
            "instanceMaxOne": 2,
            "instanceMinTwo": 4,
            "instanceMaxTwo": 6,
        },
    }

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `{{- range $idx, $nodeName := .Parameters.nodes }}
   instance-min: {{ index $.Parameters (print "instanceMin" $nodeName) }}
   instance-max: {{ index $.Parameters (print "instanceMax" $nodeName) }}
{{- end }}`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/mlxoCdcPD3D)):

```
instance-min: 1
instance-max: 2
instance-min: 4
instance-max: 6
```

Comment: Damnit, `{{ index $.Parameters $key }}` I can't believe this. I was trying `{{ index .Parameters $key }}` and it didn't work and had given up that route

Comment: @Alexis The `{{range}}` action changes the dot, so you need `$` to reference outside of the loop variable.